# parsing trough a JSON html string to obtain key-value pairs?

Tags: api, json, html, string, parser

Im calling an API and after parsing trough the json this is the part I need:

```
"description": "<b>Precipitating Event</b> updated from:  to: testing update\n<b>Age</b> updated from: 15 to: 16\n<b>sllocation</b> updated from: to: Sober Living\n"
```

how can I parse trough this string? specifically I want to store the values that come right after the **'to: '** of *Precipitating Event*, *Age*, and *sllocation*

Comment: use regex; you can get specific regex help on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, you can use regex to isolate string parts, with a combination of positive lookbehind and lookahead assertions.

eg. `'(?m)(?<=to:)\s*(.+?)\s*(?=\n)'`

- **(.+?)**: the value you are looking for
- **(?<=to:)**: positive lookbehind to delimit the start
- **(?=\n)**: positive lookahead to delimit the end (can be replaced, in this case, by '$' because it must be the end of the line)
- **\s***: removes extra spaces (trim)
- **(?m)**: multiline modifier (required in this case - Apex syntax)

With this regex, you will obtain the values by iterating on the matcher first group.

By modifying it and based on your ws response example, you can also get the keys and the values by using the matcher structure: `'(?m)((?<=<b>)(.+?)(?=</b>))(.+?)(?<=to:)\\s*(.+?)\\s*$'`. The key is between `<b>` and `</b>` (group 2) and the value is between `to:` and the end of line (group 4)

Example implementation in Apex (using both regex)

```
String wsResponse = '<b>Precipitating Event</b> updated from:  to:    testing update \n<b>Age</b> updated from: 15 to: 16\n<b>sllocation</b> updated from: to: Sober Living\n';

// first pattern with value identification
static final String MY_PATTERN_1 = '(?m)(?<=to:)\\s*(.+?)\\s*(?=\\n)';

Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile(MY_PATTERN_1);
Matcher myMatcher = myPattern.matcher(wsResponse);

Map<String, String> mapValues = new Map<String, String>();
List<String> results = new List<String>();

while (myMatcher.find()) {
    System.debug(myMatcher.group(1));
    results.add(myMatcher.group(1));
}

if (results.size() == 3) {
    mapValues.put('Precipitating Event', results[0]);
    mapValues.put('Age', results[1]);
    mapValues.put('sllocation', results[2]);
    System.debug('result map: ' + mapValues);
} else {
    System.debug('No Match or incorrect ws response');
}

// Second pattern using key and value identification
static final String MY_PATTERN_2 = '(?m)((?<=<b>)(.+?)(?=</b>))(.+?)(?<=to:)\\s*(.+?)\\s*$';
Matcher myMatcher2 = Pattern.compile(MY_PATTERN_2).matcher(wsResponse);

Map<String, String> mapValues2 = new Map<String, String>();

while (myMatcher2.find()) {
    System.debug('Key: "' + myMatcher2.group(2) + '" value: "' +  myMatcher2.group(4) + '"');
    mapValues2.put(myMatcher2.group(2),myMatcher2.group(4));
}

System.debug('result map: ' + mapValues2);
```

Debug console:

```
USER_DEBUG|[13]|DEBUG|testing update
USER_DEBUG|[13]|DEBUG|16
USER_DEBUG|[13]|DEBUG|Sober Living
USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|result map: {Age=16, Precipitating Event=testing update, sllocation=Sober Living}
USER_DEBUG|[33]|DEBUG|Key: "Precipitating Event" value: "testing update"
USER_DEBUG|[33]|DEBUG|Key: "Age" value: "16"
USER_DEBUG|[33]|DEBUG|Key: "sllocation" value: "Sober Living"
USER_DEBUG|[37]|DEBUG|result map: {Age=16, Precipitating Event=testing update, sllocation=Sober Living}
```

Comment: +1 for your patience and time to answer the OP